# Windows Work flow - Exposing Multiple Service Receives using Pick activity

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am constructing a WF4 workflow that needs more than one method. I am using the pick activity so each receive can activate the workflow, and do it's work in any order, (like a normal WCF service functions). However, every time I call either one of the web service, both triggers end up being called regardless of what method I call (both methods have the same signature).

Should I be using something besides the pick activity to accomplish this? Perhaps a parallel activity?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel activity is the best if you would have x different messaging activities and you would want all of them to be called, but in no particular order.

Hmm...did you say that both methods have the same signature and they are in pick activity ?
Why do you have 2 methods then ? you should have a Receive activity before pick and then have a rule to go to specific branch based on parameters from Receive call.

Hope it helps.

Comment: well they have the same signature but different operation names
GetX(string a)
GetY(string b)

Comment: right, is the functinality different or same for these methods?

Comment: well different, they are performing different operations to the same entity, I am attempting to expose the workflow as a service with multiple operations, for my purposes they do not have to be in the same workflow per se, just as long as whoever is calling the service it appears that it function similar to a 'normal' wcf service, for lack of a better term.